# Reset a field in all field of the collection in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604f3a4d5ad6670507b7ead4"),
        "socialStats" : [ 
            {
                "$ref" : "socialStats",
                "$id" : ObjectId("604f4f883b18ab7883ce3aba")
            }, 
            {
                "$ref" : "socialStats",
                "$id" : ObjectId("604f5000da171840ec32bd3d")
            }
        ],
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604f3a4d5ad6670507b7ead4"),
        "socialStats" : [ 
            {
                "$ref" : "socialStats",
                "$id" : ObjectId("604f4f883b18ab7883ce3aba")
            }, 
            {
                "$ref" : "socialStats",
                "$id" : ObjectId("604f5000da171840ec32bd3d")
            }
        ],
    }
```

i have a mongo collection "asset"
i want to update "socialStats":[] in all the records of collection
What will be the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [update Method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with blank search Object and with `{multi : true }` option.

Here, I use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator

```
db.collection.update({},
  {
     "$set": {
        "socialStats": []
     }
 },
 {
  "multi": true 
 })
```

If you not use `{multi: true}` only one document is going to be updated.

**OR**

You can also do this by using [db.collection.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method.

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
 {
    "$set": {
       "socialStats": []
    }
})
```